# Getting extension from uri

Tags: android

Hello it is possible to get extension from URI in android, or File varriable?  I have `Intent.Action_Open_Document` and I need to check the extension. This is serializable file

Answer (score 1):

> I have Intent.Action_Open_Document and I need to check the extension.

A `Uri` does not have to have a file extension, in part because it does not have to have a filename. From your standpoint, a `Uri` is an opaque string.

For example, `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44810016/getting-extension-from-uri` is a `Uri`. There is no file extension.

Use a `ContentResolver` and `getType()` to retrieve the MIME type associated with the content identified by the `Uri`. If, for some reason, you still need a file extension, and this is a commonly-known MIME type, try `MimeTypeMap`.

Comment: it is `application/octet-stream` by extension is mine